# Which Axis and Allies Game Takes the Least Amount of Time to Play?

Tags: axis-and-allies, play-time

I have A&A Europe.  I generally just play with one other person.  The problem is that the game takes so long to play that we rarely play - because it takes so long.  Do different editions take more or less time to play?

Answer (score 1):

A&A Pacific takes significantly less time to play than standard.  While I havent played Europe, BGG says that estimated time is 210 minutes as opposed to 120 for Pacific, so pacific should be shorter. Its about 2-3 hours, depends how willing to concede defeat the players are and. Additionally, it works excellently with 2 players. I would give that a try.. Have fun

Answer (score 0):

From the "normal" game the 1st edition is a little bit shorter than the 2nd and the anniversary edition because the rules are easier and you do not need to read/learn/memorize it. But in general the normal game will be long too. Never played a game under 4-5 hours and even then one side "just" gave up.

Answer (score -1):

Axis and allies 1941 takes the least to play at 1.5 -2 hours and is also the cheapest edition.